# circle PNG image making it interactive on android

Tags: java, android

Well i have a circle image that i am using imageview to show in the app

I need someway to make parts of this image interactive like event should fire depend on which part of the image the user is clicking , i.e. if user is clicking on the center of the image or on one of the pie slices of the circle image

how this could be achived ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be slicing the image into the parts, then assigning a clickevent to each part with the appropriate reaction.

the other way could be to check on the clickevent where you have clicked (x,y) and check if it is in a range you defined as an area if it's in there.

or you have different colors of the slices, you then get the color of the clicked pixel and evaluate where it belongs to

Comment: how can i get the color of the clicked pixle ?

Comment: also if i am checking the X,y of the click then how it will work on diffrent screen sizes

Comment: you're right, for differen screensizes, you can't directly work with the values of x and y, but you can compare them to the screensize ex: xRatio = x / screenwidth;   for the color look at this example int c = image.getRGB(x,y);
int  red = (c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int  green = (c & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int  blue = c & 0x000000ff;
// and the Java Color is ...
Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);